# Career link redirects to a different URL

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I was browsing Stack Overflow as usual and thought to click on one the job links in the right panel.

But to my surprise every time I clicked on the links, it would take me to a job/page not found page. And the URL seems to be different that what the job title says.

Below is an example

[image]

When I click on third link on above page, it would take me to this page (notice the URL on that page and the job title on above page)

[image]